# How to find whether a given address is in heap or in stack

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc

I have a requirement to find whether a given address is in heap or in stack. Is there a reliable way to do this in Linux?

I have thought about the following approach assuming that the stack will grow downward and heap will grow up towards stack. How reliable is this solution? We don't use `gcc split-stack`.

```
is_stack (void *addr) {
   int a;
   if( &a < addr) return stack;
   else return heap
}
```

[edit - I saw a similar question but that's more of a theoretical nature]

Comment: Why exactly do you ask?

Comment: [See ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch :-) Because I see it broken in some platforms (all Linux with minor version changes).

Comment: @user3386109 Can you elaborate how and why ASLR come in to this picture? As I understand, ASLR has no role once the process is in memory

Comment: It is a short way of saying your function will not be reliable because the address (for a statically declared value) you are testing against could well be less than `a` and still be on the `stack` according the your function.

Comment: ASLR will place the stack at some random location in the virtual memory space, and the heap at some other random location. So you can't assume any relationship between stack addresses and heap addresses.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "I see it broken in some platforms"? *What* is broken?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This logic was working fine all through years and it stopped working on a new platform with similar environment.

Comment: @user3386109 ok. that's what is causing the issue then.  Does ASLR have any say about stack growing down or UP?

Comment: No, the direction the stack grows is primarily determined by the processor instructions that manipulate the stack, specifically the call/return and push/pop instructions. On most processors, the stack grows down, but you can't rely on that (if you want portable future-proof code).

Comment: I can't help but feel that the practical problem you're trying to solve needs a different approach. What is your [problem X](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you may have several stacks in your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), in particular if it is multi-threaded (and some libraries could start threads without you asking for them). And your process' [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) might have more segments than just *heap* & *stack*.

You might parse the `/proc/self/maps` pseudo-file. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Notice that since it is a pseudo-file which is generated by the kernel, there is no physical IO involved, and reading & parsing that `/proc/self/maps` file should be really quick.

The address map of your process can change by calling [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), `munmap`, `execve`, `mprotect` and some other system calls (see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)
 to get a list of them); use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand which syscalls are done. Any call to `malloc` (internally called by many functions, including `fopen`...) or to `free` (and to `dlopen` etc etc....) *could* (but won't always) use them, so caching the result of parsing `/proc/self/maps` is not a reliable option.

Try first the `cat /proc/$$/maps` command in a terminal (showing you a description of your shell's virtual address space).

As many commented, because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), you don't have any idea of the relative position of stack and heap, even if there is one single stack. A possible trick could be to start your `main` with something putting the address of some local variable (or even of `main`'s `argc` first argument, or of `argv[0]`) in some global `void*stackbottom;`, and to later compare the address like you do, that is test `if( &a < addr && &a > stackbottom)`. Notice that [Boehm's garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc) is doing similar things.

But the most reliable way is to read and parse `/proc/self/maps` and that should be fairly quick and is certainly a programmatic solution (the kernel is *dynamically* giving information about its state and the process state thru `/proc/` and no *physical* IO is involved reading it).

And still, be on stack or be in heap is an ill-defined property of pointers (in other words, *stack* or *heap* is a much more complex notion than what you imagine). You need to be more precise about what you really want to do.

Alterrnatively, redefine your own `malloc`, `free` etc and have your `malloc` manage some memory map.

Comment: thanks for the answer!
Assume that this is a controlled single threaded environment. No, proc is not a solution. I want to do it programmatically. Care to comment on the solution I posted?

Comment: On the contrary, reading `/proc/self/maps` is the most reliable programmatic solution.

Comment: Thanks for the trick. This logic is going to be in a very performance critical part. Based on this I need to free up certain memory. Parsing the proc/map everytime doesn't look like a solution. Parsing  proc/maps once and keeping the data seems fine.

Comment: But the map is changing, and could change at any `malloc` or `free` or `dlopen` or `mmap`

Comment: @joe: did you consider using simply Boehm's GC: replace all your calls to `malloc` with `GC_malloc` and remove all calls to `free`.

Comment: Thanks again. First time hearing about this GC. Let me try to understand what it is. Though I can't replace entire malloc system now. Let me see if I can borrow some concepts. 
btw, in which scenario you think the stack beginning solution may not work ?

Answer (score 4):

The C standard doesn't have a notion of a *heap* or a *stack*, so the language itself can't tell you.

But you do mention Linux so all is not lost - you can achieve this with a fair bit of work.

If you define the *heap* as being the memory allocated by `malloc`, you *could* consider building your own memory allocation system. Many C compilers allow you to imbue a different `malloc` at link-time for *all* libraries linked into your program, so this approach is quite feasible. (See LD_PRELOAD). Of course the main guts of your replacement `malloc` will simply call the standard function. But the other part will maintain a table of allocated memory. You can use that information in the test function that you'll need to write.

You'll need to do the same for `calloc`, `free`, &c.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am looking for something as simple as the solution I posted. Can you tell me why would that not work?

Comment: Why *would* it? It's predicated on your assumption which you can't justify in the context of the standard. I also don't like `&a < addr`: that's UB (I think) if `addr` did not start life as a pointer to `int`.

Comment: oh no. First, see it as pseudo code. And we are trying to compare the addresses here. Let's not worry about the type. Point is whether the logic will work or not.

Comment: I can't see it working. The assumptions are incorrect. By the way, there's nothing wrong with your question.

Comment: this is working fine for 3 years in the minimum. It just stopped working in a new platform presumably because of ASLR.

Comment: @joe What exactly do you mean by a "new platform"? There might be all kinds of reasons why the positions of the stack and the heap seem inverted. ASLR is not the only possible reason if you're working on with different processor architecture, a different operating system, or even a different compiler. Fact remains that this question is very much tied to specific implementations. As pointed out in this answer, "stack" and "heap" are not really defined in C, which implies that you can't write one version of this function that is guaranteed to work on all implementations.

Comment: @Rhymoid New platform is a different product altogether. However in our problem perspective, it just means a different Linux version. The GCC version also is different. One 4.3 and other 4.6